# cURL surpress progress stats after cURL download has finished

Tags: bash, shell, unix, curl

I have this simple script:

```
printf "* Download Status: Pending..."

# Get HTML content from homepage
homepage=$(curl -s "https://example.com/")
wait

printf "\r* Download Status: Successful\n"
```

The `\r` simulates carriage return and prints `Download Status: Successful` after the download finishes, hereby removing `Download Status: Pending...`. This works flawlessly.

If I omit the `-s` flag, `curl` will show the statistics until the download is complete.

- How can I show the statistics during the download and remove them when `curl` is finished?

I tried using something like:

```
printf "< Download Status: Pending...\n\n"

# Get HTML content from homepage
homepage=$(curl "https://example.com/")
wait

printf "\r\r\r\r\r\r> Download Status: Successful\n"
```

The reason for me using that many `\r` is because I'm leaving some space at the beginning (`\n`) and the `curl` statistics themselves are 3 lines long. I thought this might remove them but it obviously doesn't, instead it outputs both of the `printf` with the `curl` stats in between them!

- Can anyone tell me why?

---

**ALTERED ANSWER**

According to @jmd_dk 's genius use of variables, this worked for my case:

```
# Set ANSI codes as variables
esc="\x1b"
esc_up="${esc}[1A"
esc_erase="${esc}[K"
newline="\n"

# Display status before download
printf "* Download Status: Pending...${newline}${newline}"

# Initiante cURL & wait for HTML content from the homepage
homepage=$(curl "https://example.com/")
wait

# Delete all lines up to download status
printf "${esc_up}${esc_erase}"
printf "${esc_up}${esc_erase}"
printf "${esc_up}${esc_erase}"
printf "${esc_up}${esc_erase}"
printf "${esc_up}${esc_erase}"

# Display status after completion
echo "* Download Status: Successful"
```

I delete all lines else some parts of the `curl` stats will be showed, making the output messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to make use of more complex (ANSI) escape sequences. Example (save this to a script before running):

```
esc="\x1b"
esc_up="${esc}[1A"
esc_erase="${esc}[K"
echo Line 1
echo Line 2
echo Line 3
sleep 3
printf "${esc_up}${esc_up}"  # Move cursor two up
printf "${esc_erase}"  # Delete current line
echo New
```

This will print the three lines, then move up two lines and overwrite the text. To understand `esc_erase`, try leaving this line out.

The world of ANSI escape sequences is vast an daunting. The above example should suffice for your immediate needs. Much more information is of course [available](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

Comment: Works like a charm @jmd_dk ! I updated my question according to your answer. The idea of using variables for the ANSI codes makes the script much clearer.

Answer (score 3):

## Carriage Return

`\r` does not delete it line, it moves the cursor to the beginning of the current line.
**Example:** `echo Test; printf '\r_'` will print `_est`.

To delete the *current* line using `\r`, you would have to use

```
printf '\r                                                      '
```

Note the spaces that will (hopefully) overwrite everything in the current line.

## Cursor Movement

`\r` always stays in the same line. Multiple subsequent `\r`s will have the same effect as just one. To delete other lines you have to use other [escape sequences](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html), such as

- `\033[<N>A` move the cursor *up* `<N>` lines.
- `\033[K` erase to end of line (just like `\r` with lots of spaces).

## Putting Everything Together

`curl` shows its progress in three lines. On top of them, there is your `Download Status: Pending..."` message. To erase them all

- `\r\033[4A` go to the left and four rows up
- `\033[K\n` delete the 1st line and go to the 2nd
- `\033[K\n` delete the 2nd line and go to the 3rd
- `\033[K\n` delete the 3rd line and go to the 4th
- `\033[K` delete the 4th line
- `\r\033[4A` go to the left and four rows up again
- `Download Status: Successful` print the new message

This leaves us with the command

```
echo "* Download Status: Pending..."
homepage=$(curl "https://example.com/")
wait
printf '\r\033[4A\033[K\n\033[K\n\033[K\n\033[K' # delete 4 lines
printf '\r\033[4A'                               # reposition cursor
echo '* Download Status: Successful'
```

You can write the last three lines as one `printf`, but that would be even harder to read.

## Alternative

If you don't mind loosing all the output (even the output from commands executed before your script), you can clear the complete screen with just one escape sequence: `\033c`.

```
echo "* Download Status: Pending..."
homepage=$(curl "https://example.com/")
wait
printf '\033c' # clear screen
echo '* Download Status: Successful'
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation @Socowi . I like the idea of using variables as they help maintain an overview. Cheers!